# How to add the keybinding of Format in Wolfram Workbench?

Tags: workbench

I want to add a shortcut to `Source->Format`,

[image]

but in the preference only the following shortcuts are provided,

[image]

Is there a way of adding new keybindings not in the preference? I searched and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052758/hidden-keybindings)
may be related, but have no idea how to realize it.